# append data to excel sheet on button click

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I have a windows application that by pressing a button it displays a number in a text box.
I want to add that number to an existing excel each time the button is clicked .

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is a good and quite easy way to do it. Check this tutorial [How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).